# Simple exec program in linux

Tags: linux, operating-system, exec

Hello every one I want to ask a question that what is "**simple exec"** I have heard it some where and I have searched for it but don't get any useful answer can any one tell me

- A program
- some thing related to operating system

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec.

Comment: where have you heard it? **exec** obviously stands for execute, so maybe it was just an instruction to execute a program or a script?

Comment: to be very honest NO.Its for my own knowledge

Comment: @twall i cant remember exactly.thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exec system call replaces your current running process with some program stored in disk. It only keeps the system segment of the original process (meaning: PID, file descriptors, and other system stuff)
It is provided by the Linux/Unix kernel and there are several ways to call it, check the various exec definitions according to POSIX in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/exec.html. A simple demostration program would be:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Giving control to ls!\n");
    execl("/usr/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
    printf("This should never be printed..\n");
    return 0;
}
```

That program prints a line and executes 'ls', so you would see the message, then the output of ls, and that's it. The last line isn't displayed because your process was replaced.

Answer (score 0):

There are exec functions in all programming languages. These are methods used to invoke the system shell/cmd in from a program.

exec functions are dangerous since they are directly interacting with the OS from external.